# Mapping Material UI Elements Using Props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, mapping, react-props

I am trying to map some material ui items to reduce the code but I also need to pass props. How could I do so?

For example, this works fine:

```
 <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="First Name" variant="outlined" onChange={e => {
                this.setState({firstName: e.target.value})
              }}             
       />
```

but this doesn't because the state firstName is passed inside props:

```
     {[{ label: 'First Name', state: {firstName}].map((item, index) => (

       <TextField id="outlined-basic" label={item.label} variant="outlined" onChange={e => {
        this.setState({{item.state}: e.target.value}) }}  

       />
          ))}
```

```
  constructor(props: Readonly<{}>) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      phone: '',
      email: '',
      password: '',
    };
  }
```